# How to remove dataframe rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove Dataframe rows using multiple conditions from one Dataframe (`df1`) based on values from a second Dataframe (df2). The data I'm interested in comparing within these dataframes is labelled 'Timestamp' (`T`) and 'delta_t' (`dt`).

The function I'm looking to apply is that when `T_{df1} == T_{df2}`, then remove all lines where `dt_{df2} - 0.1 < dt_{df1} < dt_{df2}`

In other words, when the timestamp values from each dataframe are equal, I then want to compare the delta_t values. If the `delta_t` values of `df_1` fall within a +/- range of 0.1 of the `delta_t` values of `df2`, then remove these rows from the df1.

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers!

I have tried using `df1.loc['timestamp'].isin(df2['timestamp']` to acquire the rows with corresponding timestamp values. BUt I'm not sure how to compare the `delta_t` values and remove lines which fall within a specific range.

EDIT:
The data is originally saved in one dataframe with many columns. One of the columns is labelled 'channels'. To form the two dataframes (df1, df2) that I compare, I separate based on the channel value using the following:

noise = df1[df1['channel'] == 3]['timestamp_copy']
df2 = df1.loc[(df1['timestamp_copy'].isin(noise))]

Therefore, the number of rows in df1 >> df2.

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correctly then this satisfies your task,
you can select the indices where your desired condition satisfied and then drop them from the dataframe `df1` as

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[10,11]],columns=['a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[11,10]],columns=['a','b'])

indices_to_removed = df1[ ( ( df1['a'] == df2['a'] ) & ( abs( df1['b'] - df2['b'] ) <= 0.1 ) ) ].index
df1 = df1.drop(indices_to_removed)
print(df1)
```

just replace `a`, and `b` with your columns names.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the kind words and the help, I really appreciate it! I have some further questions after trying to implement your suggestions. When I run with these lines I get the value error of "Can only compare identically-labeled series objects". The data frames I am using are not of the same length, would this be the reason for this error? Thanks again for your time and help!!

Comment: Hi , Thanks! . Yes this problem can happen if your dataframes are of different sizes , so how would you like to handle rows df1 that doesn't have mirror rows in df2 to check ? for example just leave them without any changes ?